# Beginner Python Code Issues

Tags: python

5.2 Write a program that repeatedly prompts a user for integer numbers until the user enters 'done'. Once 'done' is entered, print out the largest and smallest of the numbers. If the user enters anything other than a valid number catch it with a try/except and put out an appropriate message and ignore the number. Enter the numbers from the book for problem 5.1 and Match the desired output as shown.

Here is my Code:

```
largest = None
smallest = None
while True:
    inp = raw_input("Enter a number: ")
    if inp == "done" : break
    try:
        num = float(inp)
    except:
        print "Invalid input"
    if smallest is None:
        smallest = num
    elif num < smallest:
        smallest = num
    elif num > largest:
        largest = num

    continue

print "Maximum is", largest
print "Minimum is", smallest
```

******Please let me know the Logic errors in this CODE*****

Comment: What have you tried, what were the results, and how do they differ from what you want.

Comment: Your ifs should be in the try block

Answer (score 2):

A: You never assign largest away from being None.

B: On the case that float(inp) fails, you still try to continue on. You shouldn't. While you *can* move those if/elif statements into the try block, I'd recommend against that, because you then run the risk of accidentally catching something you shouldn't. Instead, use try/except's much neglected `else` block.

In the same line, it's good practice only except the error you want to and not all errors.

C: No continue necessary

```
largest = None
smallest = None
while True:
    inp = raw_input("Enter a number: ")
    if inp == "done" : break
    try:
        num = float(inp)
    except ValueError: #and not all errors!
        print "Invalid input"
    else: 
        # This block will execute if no exception is caught.
        # Yes, this is valid python.
        if smallest is None: #first number!
            smallest = num
            largest = num
        elif num < smallest:
            smallest = num
        elif num > largest:
            largest = num

print "Maximum is", largest
print "Minimum is", smallest
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the correct answer[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ST5zP.png)

largest = None
smallest = None

inp_list = []
while True:
    inp = raw_input("Enter a number: ")
    if inp == "done":
        break
    else:
        inp_list.append(inp)

for num in inp_list:
    try:
        num = int(num)
        if smallest is None:
            smallest = num 
        if num > largest :
            largest = num
        elif num < smallest :
            smallest = num
    except:
        print ('Invalid input')

print ("Maximum is", int(largest))
print ("Minimum is", int(smallest))

Answer (score 0):

Write a program that repeatedly prompts a user for integer numbers until the user enters 'done'. Once 'done' is entered, print out the largest and smallest of the numbers. If the user enters anything other than a valid number catch it with a try/except and put out an appropriate message and ignore the number.

```
largest = None
smallest = None

while True:
    inp = raw_input("Enter a number: ")

    if inp == "done":
        break

    try:
        num = int(inp)

        if smallest is None:
            smallest = num
        elif num < smallest:
            smallest = num
        elif num > largest:
           largest = num
    except:
        print "Invalid input"

    continue

print "Maximum is", largest
print "Minimum is", smallest
```

error if mismatch appears after execution

Comment: first of all - you are catching too many exceptions, narrow it, there is no need for `continue` at the end of the loop, third - your algorithm to update smallest/largest have holes in it... need fixing

Answer (score 0):

```
largest = None
smallest = None
while True:
    inp = raw_input("Enter a number: ")
    if inp == "done" : break
    try:
        num = int(inp)
    except:
        print "Invalid input"
        continue
    if smallest is None:
        smallest = num
    elif num < smallest:
        smallest = num
    if largest is None:
        largest = num
    elif num > largest:
        largest = num

print "Maximum is", largest
print "Minimum is", smallest
```

Comment: Please explain your answer. A solution posted with no explanation doesn't help the OP understand the answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
largest = None
smallest = None
while True:
    num = raw_input("Enter a number:")
    if num == "done": break
    try: 
       nom = int(num)
    except: 
       print "Invalid input"
       continue

    if largest is None:
        largest = nom
    elif nom >  largest:
        largest = nom

    if smallest is None:
        smallest = nom
    elif nom < smallest:
        smallest = nom


print "Maximum is", largest
print "Minimum is", smallest
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to help others in the future. Refer to [answer]

Answer (score 0):

You should include your logic in your try: block to run this program logically. It will run even if you put your logic inside the catch block.

Placing the logic (if/else) after the catch is not able to calculate your highest and lowest number for the number you entered before the Error caught.

**Correct Method**

```
largest = None
smallest = None
while True:
    num = input("Enter a number: ")
    if num == 'done': break
    try:
        ival = int(num)
                # This block will execute if no exception is caught.
        # Yes, this is valid python.
        if smallest is None: #first number!
            smallest = ival
            largest = ival
        elif ival  largest:
            largest = ival

    except ValueError: #and not all errors!
        print ('Invalid input')
        continue 


print('Maximum is', largest)
print('Minimum is', smallest)
```

**Wrong Method**

```
    largest = None
    smallest = None
    while True:
        num = input("Enter a number: ")
        if num == 'done': break
        try:
            ival = int(num)
        except ValueError:
            print ('Invalid input')
            continue 
    if smallest is None:
                smallest = ival
                largest = ival
            elif ival  largest:
                largest = ival

    print('Maximum is', largest)
    print('Minimum is', smallest)
```

Answer (score 0):

Code:

```
largest = None
smallest = None

while True:
num = input("Enter a number: ")
if num == "done":
    break
try:
    n = int(num)
    if smallest is None or n < smallest:
        smallest = n
    if largest is None or n > largest:
        largest = n
except ValueError:
    # num cannot be converted to an int
    print ("Invalid input")

print("Maximum is", largest)
print("Minimum is", smallest)
```

Output:

```
Invalid input
Maximum is 10
Minimum is 2
```

Answer (score 0):

```
largest = None
smallest = None
while True:
    inp = raw_input("Enter a number: ")
    if inp == "done" : break
    try:
        num = int(inp)
    except ValueError: #and not all errors!
        print ("Invalid input")
    else: 
        # This block will execute if no exception is caught.
        # Yes, this is valid python.
        if smallest is None: #first number!
            smallest = num
            largest = num
        elif num < smallest:
            smallest = num
        elif num > largest:
            largest = num

print ("Maximum is", largest)
print ("Minimum is", smallest)
```

Comment: Hi there! Tip: please tell us _why_ your code answers the question, as well as _how_. Aside from that, to format your code you must highlight it and click the `{}` button on the question/answer editor. I have proposed an edit to format your code already.

Answer (score 0):

```
#by Aless
largest  = None
smallest = None
while True:
    num = input("Enter a number: ")
    if num == "done" : break

    try:
        intNum = int(num)
    except ValueError:
        #print('Error: Invalid input', num)
        print('Invalid input')
        continue
    else:
        if (largest  < intNum): largest = intNum
        if (smallest > intNum) or (smallest is None): smallest = intNum

print("Maximum", largest)
print("Minimum", smallest)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
largest = 0
smallest = None
while True:
    num = input("Enter a number: ")
    if num == "done" : 
        break
    try:
        num1=int(num)
        if(num1>largest):
            largest=num1
        elif((smallest is None) or(num1<smallest)):
            smallest=num1
    except ValueError:
        print("Invalid input")    
        continue

print("Maximum is", largest)
print("Minimum is",smallest)
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score 0):

```
largest = None
smallest = None
numbers = []
while True:
    num = input("Enter a number: ")
    if num == "done":
    break
    numbers.append(num)

for value in numbers:
    try:
        value = int(value) 
        if largest is None:
            largest = value
        elif value > largest:
            largest = value
    except:
        continue

for value in numbers:
    try:
        value = int(value)
        if smallest is None:
            smallest = value
        elif value < smallest:
            smallest = value
    except:
        print ("Invalid input")
        continue       `

print("Maximum is", largest)
print("Minimum is", smallest)
```

Comment: can you give a bit of explanation?

Comment: A list to save the input by users including both string and int. when done is entered it saves the input to the list called numbers.  loop through the numbers to determine the largest value using for loop bearing in mind that the list also contains string hence the try and except block in the first for loop, similarly, for the second loop but notice in the second loop under the error catching block, there is a line of code that accounts for the string (this can also be placed in the first error catching block whichever you prefer). Finally i printed out the maximum and minimum numbers

Answer (score 0):

```
largest = None
smallest = None
while True:
    num = input("Enter a number: ")
    if num == 'done': break
    try:
        ival = int(num)
                # This block will execute if no exception is caught.
        # Yes, this is valid python.
        if smallest is None: #first number!
            smallest = ival
            largest = ival
        elif ival>largest:
            largest = ival
        elif ival<smallest:
            smallest=ival

    except ValueError: #and not all errors!
        print ('Invalid input')
        continue 

print('Maximum is', largest)
print('Minimum is', smallest)
```

Comment: While this code may provide a solution to OP's problem, it is highly recommended that you provide additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question. Code only answers typically become useless in the long-run because future viewers experiencing similar problems cannot understand the reasoning behind the solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
largest = None
smallest = None

while True:
inp = input("Enter a number: ")

if inp == "done" : break
try:
    num = float(inp)
except ValueError: 
    print ("Invalid input")
else: 
    if smallest is None:
        smallest = num
        largest = num
    elif num < smallest:
        smallest = num
    elif num > largest:
        largest = num   
print ("Maximum is", int(largest))   
print ("Minimum is", int(smallest))
```

Comment: Can you explain your solution, and format your code?

Comment: sorry .. i edited it see it now you will understand

Answer (score 0):

5.2 Write a program that repeatedly prompts a user for integer numbers until the user enters 'done'. Once 'done' is entered, print out the largest and smallest of the numbers. If the user enters anything other than a valid number catch it with a try/except and put out an appropriate message and ignore the number. Enter 7, 2, bob, 10, and 4 and match the output below.

```
largest = None
smallest = None
while True:
    num = input("Enter a number: ")
    if num == "done" :
        break
    try:
        a = int(num)
    except:
        print("Invalid input") 
        continue
    if a > largest:
        largest = a
    if smallest is None:
        smallest = a
    if  a < smallest:
    smallest = a

print("Maximum is", largest)
print("Minimum is", smallest)
```

Inputs

```
7
2
bob
10
4
done
```

Output

```
Invalid input
Maximum is 10
Minimum is 2
```

Answer (score 0):

#Try this code. its working please see the screenshot use 7,4,bob, 10,4 and last "done".

```py
largest = None
smallest = None

while True:
    try:
        num = raw_input("Enter a number: ")
        if num == "done":
            break
        if largest is None:
            largest = int(num)
        if int(num) > largest:
            largest = int(num)
        if smallest is None:
            smallest = int(num)
        if int(num) < smallest:
            smallest = int(num)
    except:
        print ("Invalid input")
print ("Maximum is", largest)
print ("Minimum is", smallest)
```

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Try this code ....

```
largest = None
smallest = None

while True:
    num = input("Enter a number: ")
    if num == "done" : 
        break 
    try:
        inp=float(num)
    except:
        print("Invalid input")
        continue

for value in [7,2,10,4]: 
    if largest is None:
        largest = value
    elif value>largest:  
        largest=value
        print("Maximum is", largest)            
for value in [7,2,10,4]: 
    if smallest is None:
        smallest = value
    elif value < smallest:
        smallest=value          
        print("Minimum is", smallest)
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.